# Chaining .apply() and .bind() surprising behaviour

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need your help to better understand the following behavior.

In the snippet below, we can see that `fooBar` outputs `foo` as `this` and then `returns bar 1, 2, 3` as expected - means `bar` is called with `foo` as context.

```js
const arguments = [1,2,3];

function bar(...args) {
  console.log('bar this ->', this);
  return 'bar ' + args;
}

function foo(...args) {
  console.log('foo this ->', this);
  return 'foo ' + args;
}

const fooBar = bar.bind(foo, null)(arguments);

console.log(fooBar); // <--- no surprises!
```

Let's now have `const bar = Math.max.apply;` instead.

```js
const arguments = [1,2,3];

const bar = Math.max.apply;

function foo(...args) {
  console.log('foo this ->', this);
  return 'foo ' + args;
}

const fooBar = bar.bind(foo, null)(arguments);

console.log(fooBar); // <--- surprise!
```

**In this case, `foo` is being called as opposed to `bar`. Why?** What is `bind()` exactly doing under the hood in this case? I'd have assumed that again `bar` should be called with `foo` as a context. The context, in this case, is `window`.

I always thought *someFunction.apply(someContext, args)* **behaves as** *someFunction.bind(someContext, null)(args)*, but in the second example *someFunction.bind(someContext, null)(args)* **behaves as** *someContext(args)*.

Comment: Why did you choose `Math.max.apply` exactly? It has no effect at all, it is the same as doing `const bar = Function.prototype.apply;` or `const bar = alert.apply`, or any other function for that matter: you are just referencing the method apply of the class `Function`.

Comment: no particular reason for this choice apart from: to confuse myself even more

Comment: @lustoykov Maybe you mean `const bar = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max)`

Comment: thanks @Bergi, this is not what confuses me. I think the answer from @lonesomeday is closest for me to understand, but something doesn't add up, since `Function.prototype.apply.apply(foo, null)(arguments)` is not a correct syntax

Comment: @lustoykov Also notice that `.bind(foo, null)(arg)` is not correct anyway. It should be `.bind(foo)(arg)` or `.bind(null)(arg)`

Comment: do you mean semantically? because syntactically bind accepts 2 optional arguments as far as I'm concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the specific purpose of `apply`: to call a given function. Remember that `bar` is the generic `Function.prototype.apply` function.

`bind` essentially creates a copy of the original function, with the context (`this` value) and (optionally) arguments preset. A polyfill for `bind` would use `apply` internally.

So `fooBar = bar.bind(foo, null)` is the same as

```
function fooBar(...args) {
    return Function.prototype.apply.apply(foo, [null, args]);
}
```

The double use of `apply` is obviously confusing!

Let's step through what `bar.bind(foo, null)(arguments)` would do:

```
Function.prototype.apply.bind(foo, null)(arguments)
```

which can be reduced to

```
Function.prototype.apply.apply(foo, [null, arguments])
```

which in this specific instance is the same as

```
foo(null, ...arguments);
```

The reason this is so confusing is that you are doing a complex invocation of the `apply` function, which is designed for complex invocations of functions!

Comment: thank you so much for the input! I'm on the road now and will look more closely when I'm home. Sounds like the correct answer though!

Answer (score 1):

`bind` is creating a new function which calls its `this` value (`bar`, which is a copy of `apply`) with the value you pass to it as the new `this` value.

Since `bar` is a copy of `apply`:

`bar.bind(foo)()` is the same as `foo.bar()` is the same as `foo.apply()`.

Comment: hey, thanks for the input! Your last sentence is correct, but I'm afraid only for the case where bar is Function.prototype.apply, here is a counter example: https://jsbin.com/maxinuwoto/1/edit?js,console. That's what I'm trying to understand - why does it behave differently in this case.

Comment: Why does it behave differently when it is apply though? Hmm... what is bind() doing exactly under the hood? If I could find the implementation somewhere! The statements are correct and that's what I've concluded as well, but I don't understand *why*

Comment: It doesn't behave differently with `apply`. `apply` just does what it does given the `this` value it gets.

Comment: @lustoykov Actually your jsbin example is not what Quentin is trying to say. For it to be the same `bar` shound be `apply` (ie `const bar = Function.prototpe.apply;`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make our own "makeshift" `myApply` that mimics the native `Function#apply` to better understand how `Function#apply` works.

```
Function.prototype.myApply = function(args) {
    // some checks should be here to see if 'this' is a function and if 'args' is an array-like
    this(...args);
}
```

It takes an array (or array-like object) containing the arguments and calls `this` (whatever `myApply` is applied to) which should be a function with each item from `args` passed as a standalone argument.

**The simple example:**

Now when you do:

```
alert.myApply(["hello, there"]);
```

`alert` is passed as `this` to `myApply` (self explanatory), and `["hello, there"]` is passed as `args` and everything works as expected.

**The confusing example:**

Now when you explicitly set the `this` of `myApply` using `bind`, `call` or even `apply` like so:

```
var myApply = alert.myApply;

var newFunction = myApply.bind(foo);
```

`newFunciton` becomes a new function (a function that is equivalent to `myApply` bound to `foo`). Calling `newFunction` is like calling `myApply` with its `this` set to `foo`. When `myApply` is called, its `this` value (which is `foo` in this case) will be called.

**Additional note:** As you can see `myApply` doesn't mess around with the context of its `this` (which is a function), so that function will be called with whatever context it was before `myApply` is called, in this particular example it's the global object `window` (`foo`'s `this` is `window`).